# Check if value in input equals a certain value JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
var enter = $('#enter').attr('value');
$('#enterButton').on("click", function() {
    if(enter == "Enter" || enter == "enter") {
        $('.loader').fadeOut(2000);
    }
});
```

This is my code so far, I also tried using:

```
var enter = $('#enter').val();
```

But still nothing worked, so can anyone help me fix this? Thanks :)

EDIT: the html is:

```
<input id="enter" type="text" placeholder="Do what it says...">
<button class="btn" id="enterButton">Go!</button>
```

EDIT FINAL:

The final answer is:

```
$('#enterButton').on("click", function() {
    var enter = $('#enter').val();
    if(enter == "Enter" || enter == "enter") {
        $('.loader').fadeOut(2000);
    }
});
```

Because, the variable was outside, and was not updating with the button click :) Thanks @dystroy

Comment: provide html also.. what is `enter`?

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using ?

Comment: @Nithesh I edited main post again

Comment: @LucasWillems Im using the google SDN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't update the value of `enter` when you click so you only test the initial value which, of course, doesn't change.

Use this :

```
$('#enterButton').on("click", function() {
    var enter = $('#enter').val();
    if(enter == "Enter" || enter == "enter") {
        $('.loader').fadeOut(2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: OP, notice how the var enter = ... line is inside the event and not outside

Comment: Just for good habits, I'd argue that `toLowerCase()` should be used (if only to reduce the number of cases to type out).

Comment: Yes, +1, it makes the code dryer, that is less code has to be changed when the condition changes, and it's probably nearer the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as well.

```
$('#enterButton').on("click", function() {
var enter = $('#enter').val();
    enter = enter.toLowerCase();
    if(enter == "enter") {
        $('.loader').fadeOut(2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, yes, but why are you assigning `enter` twice?

Comment: Yes, I know. But that's the kind of thing to put into the answer, not a comment to the answer. It's not required at all (hence no down-vote for the answer), but it seems needless to *not* chain a string-method to a string and instead assign, and then modify, a variable, when you could do it (as you commented) all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
var enter = $('#enter').val();
$(document).on("click", "#enterButton", function() {
    if(enter == "Enter" || enter == "enter") {
        $('.loader').fadeOut(2000);
    }
});
```